# Rails Server Cannot Find rmagick-created Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, facebook-opengraph, rmagick

Question at the top: How do I create and save an image in Rails such that my staging/production server can read it properly for purposes of meta tags and open graph?

So I have the gem `rmagick` up and running, creating images like a champ:

```
        file_name = "#{@statement.id}.png"
        file_path = "public/assets/" + file_name

        canvas = Magick::Image.new(300, 100){self.background_color = 'white'}
        gc = Magick::Draw.new
        gc.pointsize(50)
        gc.text(30,70, "#{@statement.text}".center(14))

        gc.draw(canvas)
        canvas.write file_path
        @img = file_name
```

and in my view I'm trying to take the image name I just created, and use it for the meta tag (for open graph purposes, etc.) a la

```
    <% file_name = '/public/assets/' + @img %>
    <meta property="og:image" content=<%= file_name %>/>
```

Buuuuuut my server is saying it can't find the image at `/public/assets/XYZ.png` despite me being able to SSH into the box and observe the file myself.

This is on a Heroku server, and I've tried turning on `config.serve_static_files = true` and `config.assets.compile = true` to no avail.

The goal, of course, is to be able to text someone a link to my site, and have this .png show up as a preview image.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access your asset without its MD5 digest.

If your asset is `public/assets/image.png`, you can only access it with its digest in the end, eg `public/assets/image-c655834251f73d7714351aa287be8556.png`.

You can do that using an ERB helper method. Try this one:

`<%= asset_path('image.png') %>`

Comment: I was under the impression the MD5 digest is created during the asset compilation step.  Is that correct?  In this situation my image is being created after that has happened, dynamically each time the user visits the website, and thus won't have an MD5 digest.